# How to navigate to a new page in react?

Tags: reactjs

I started to create my own React app so I could learn better. I want to click on  and it will bring me to the About.js render. About.js is an entirely new page and new design. Sort of like  in HTML. About.js will have a whole new design but I'm not sure on how to go about this. I've used react-router but when i click on , it will not jump to another page. About.js will just render on App.js.

//App.js

```
const styles= {
  backgroundColor: '#86e1f7', 
  transition: 'all 0.2s ease-in',
  opacity: .75
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='mainCat' >
        <Category style={{width: '25%', height: '100%'}} 
            title='ABOUT' background={AboutImage} position='-73px 0'/>

        <Category style={{width: '25%', height: '100%'}} 
            title='BLOG' background={BlogImage} position='-300px 0'/>

        <Category style={{width: '25%', height: '100%'}} 
            title='CONTACT' background={ContactImage} position='-30px 0'/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

class Category extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {
        height: 0,
        marginTop: 500,
        visibility: 'hidden'
    }
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseOver() {
    this.setState({
      height: 50,
      marginTop: 450,
      visibility: 'visible' 
    });
  }

  handleMouseLeave() {
    this.setState({
      height: 0,
      marginTop: 500,
      visibility: 'hidden' 
    });
  }

    render() {
      return(
        <div className='catName' style={{...this.props.style, background: `url(${this.props.background}) ${this.props.position} white no-repeat`,  backgroundSize: 'cover', overflow: 'hidden'}} 
              onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>
            <div style={{...styles, height: this.state.height, marginTop: this.state.marginTop, visibility: this.state.visibility}}>
                <h2 className='catTitle'>{this.props.title}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

//About.js

```
export class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>About page</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with your react router implementation. can we see your code with react router? and which react router version you are using?

Comment: @DularaMalindu sure

Answer (score 4):

You may use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

here is an example from the docs:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Index = () => <h2>Home</h2>;
const About = () => <h2>About</h2>;
const Users = () => <h2>Users</h2>;

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about/">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/users/">Users</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
      <Route path="/about/" component={About} />
      <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Example: Nested Routing

This example shows how nested routing works. The route /topics loads the Topics component, which renders any further 's conditionally on the paths :id value.import React from "react";

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Home = () => <h2>Home</h2>;
const About = () => <h2>About</h2>;
const Topic = ({ match }) => <h3>Requested Param: {match.params.id}</h3>;
const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.path}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);
const Header = () => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
);

export default App;
```

Here is the link of the library documentation : [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: does all the components have to be on the same file (App.js) in order for it to work? Because I put About.js in it's own file and it has the About component. So App.js has the navigation and when you click on one of the Categories, it will redirect you to another page (brand new). Once someone clicks on a category, I dont want anything from App.js to show. I know this isnt what React.js is suppose to do since it's a SPA.

Comment: no, you can split the code into more than file one component per file for example. and use export/ import between files ...